# Cannot Disable Spring Security in Spring Boot 2.0.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am trying to disable spring security for request to frontend. I am using oauth2-auto-configuration as a dependency, also i have removed spring starter security from maven. Also i need to say that everything is working from Postman.

[Login required when requesting API's from frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W15yt.png)

Security Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@Order(SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
}

@Autowired
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return authenticationProvider;
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/","/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
            .and().httpBasic().disable();
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
}


@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}


}
```

application.properties

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=music-test-oauth2-2

security.oauth2.resource.id=oauth2_application
access_token.validity_period=3600
refresh_token.validity_period=10000
```

dependencies from pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

CORS Filter

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**");
        }
    };
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's the error you are getting when you are requesting from the client? Might be CORS issue?

Comment: Mostly a cors issue

Comment: @deen i have have implemented a cors filter in config let me show you

Comment: @PrasadReddy i have just posted the cors filter configurer

Comment: @ArsenCenko can you put logger into it and check if it's printing or not?

Comment: @deen i put a sout into the bean and it prints out.

Comment: @ArsenCenko would be easy if you try to give the error logs from frontend browser console.

Comment: @deen there are no error logs from frontend becouse in a register module i tried firsty to generate a read token and then it gives me a popup from localhost:8080 to login

Comment: @ArsenCenko without error logs it's hard to identify but as you said it's working from postman I'm suspected there must be a CORS issue. I am giving the answer for CORS. Let me know if it's work.

Comment: @deen how can i solve this cors issue ?

Comment: @ArsenCenko I have posted answer, let me know if it's work or not

Answer (score 0):

Implement Following CORS class and see if it's working-

```
@Component
public class CorsFilter  implements WebFilter  {

@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    if (exchange != null) {
        exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range");
        exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");

        if (exchange.getRequest().getMethod() == HttpMethod.OPTIONS) {
            exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
            exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
            return Mono.empty();
        } else {
            exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range");
            return chain.filter(exchange);
        }

    } else {
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }

}
}
```

Second you need to scan CorsFilter class for that in you main class do following-

```
@ComponentScan(value = "com.cors.filter", // Your CorsFilter class package path
    useDefaultFilters = false)
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.
        run(MainClass.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Update:**
Add Following dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: what is Mono, it is a model ?

Comment: it also request to implements other methods

Comment: @ArsenCenko Are you facing any issue while implementing this?

Comment: yes i am having problems with Mono model and implementing other methods into class

Comment: @ArsenCenko I have updated the post, can you try with adding a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple CORF-Filter that you can try:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Content-Type");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(((HttpServletRequest) req).getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    }
}
```

Maybe your request Headers are not correct, try to use this code:

```
public obtainAccessToken(username: string, password: string): Promise<void> {
    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append('username', username);
    params.append('password', password);    
    params.append('grant_type','password');
    params.append('client_id','fooClientIdPassword');
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8', 'Authorization': 'Basic '+btoa("fooClientIdPassword:secret")});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(environment.apiEndpointAuth + 'user/login', params.toString(), options)
        .toPromise().then(response => {
            this.saveToken(response.json());

        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: Hello @JohnnyAW i have implemented this class and it removes the login required but gives me this issue on frontend : https://ibb.co/mF2Wrx Thanks :)

Comment: well there is something wrong going with the `OPTIONS`. Could you remove everything about `OPTIONS` from your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`?

Comment: if i remove HTTP.Options from SecurityConfig it gives me 401 non authorized also from backend

Comment: can you post the backend logs? Options-Request would be actually handled by the Filter itself, so it shouldn't be a problem. The fact, that the backend returns 401 on the OPTIONS-request means, that you somehow mis configured the OPTIONS-handling

Comment: The backend not giving any logs, but on postman side you should see this generating a token https://ibb.co/gTKxyc

Comment: wait, what is `POST` - `user/login` supposed to do? You are using OAUTH2, you should get your token from the Auth-Server at `oauth/token` or something?

Comment: I have changed the pathMapping to a new one wich is /user/login it is the same.

Comment: check my update, I think you are not providing the right headers for the token request

Comment: still the same error, i dont understand where the error is

Comment: also i need to say that the CorsFilter implementation is giving 401 code also on postman

Comment: Hello, i have done the Register Part and Generate Token successfully on angular side but when i try to login it gives me this https://i.stack.imgur.com/W15yt.png, login code : https://ibb.co/kLm2EH

Comment: the problem was that i should pass the content type as application/x-www-form-urlencoded also the Basic Auth

Comment: so did you fix the issue? Your headers in angular were wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i should have to pass the content type on headers as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' also i have to pass the Basic Auth to header generated from client_id also client_secert.

Thanks :)